# Suppose $G$ is a finite group with nontrivial center $C$, then does $G/C$ have trivial center?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with nontrivial center $C$, then does $G/C$ have trivial center ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For statements like this I think you can try to either (1) Try to prove it. It can't be that hard if it's true so things will either go good or bad really quickly. (2) Test things out on groups of small order. I think it would be good to look at the two nonabelian groups of order $8$.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, if $G$ is a group,of order $p^3,$ with center of order $p,$ then $G/C$ is of order $p^2.$ Since a $p$-group cannot have trivial center, this shows that $G/C$ need not have trivial center.
Actually any non-abelian group of order $p^3$ has center with order $p,$ as shown by [this paper by *K.Conrad*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf).

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
The answer by @Bof furnishes a concrete example of the above. :P

Comment: I think its interesting that you don't actually need a counter-example here, you simply need to know a non-abelian p-group exists! As then there exists a minimal $n$ such that all groups of order $p^{n-1}$ are abelian but there exists some non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^n$. Then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian as required.

Answer (score 4):

The [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ has nontrivial center $C=\{\pm1\};$ and $Q/C,$ a group of order $4,$ is Abelian and so has nontrivial center.